# Some processes will not start when `systemctl reload httpd` is executed

Tags: apache, redhat

Some processes will not start when `systemctl reload httpd` is executed.
To be precise, some processes will not start up at odd times of execution.

**Procedure**

```
$ systemctl reload httpd
  grep - v grep | grep - v log | wc - l
    11
  $ systemctl reload httpd
  grep - v grep | grep - v log | wc - l
    twenty one
  $ systemctl reload httpd
  grep - v grep | grep - v log | wc - l
    11
```

Only 11 processes will be activated for the first time, and 21 processes will start for the second time.
In the third time, only 11 processes are activated again, so it turned out that some processes did not start up odd times.

**httpd.conf**

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit 20
    ThreadLimit 10
    StartServers 20
    MaxRequestWorkers 200
    MinSpareThreads 100
    MaxSpareThreads 200
    ThreadsPerChild 10
    MaxConnectionsPerChild 0
</ IfModule>
```

**Environment**

```
Rhel 7
Apache 2.4
```

There is no problem with `systemctl restart httpd`.
21 processes for ServerLimit are running.

We are using reload because we want to execute with lotate.